# Watir cycle through class elements

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

How can I cycle through all the elements?

I'm looking for something like:

```
brower.text_field[0](:name, "asdf").click # get the first element
brower.text_field[1](:name, "asdf").click # get the second element
```

Is there a good documentation for more advanced stuff?
I haven't found anything useful all I got is simple stuff but I'm looking for something where I can chain elements like:

```
browser.tr(:id, "asdf").td.click
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle through all matching elements, you are looking for ["element collections"](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/ElementCollection).

Basically you need to pluralize the method used to get elements and then you can use the `[]` to get a specific index:

```
brower.text_fields(:name, "asdf")[0].click # get the first element
brower.text_fields(:name, "asdf")[1].click # get the second element
```

The element collection includes Enumerable, so there are also a variety of methods for iterating.

In terms of documentation, you can look into:

- The Ruby Docs - http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver
- There are also a couple of in progress books on Leanpub if you search for Watir - https://leanpub.com/book_search?search=watir

Answer (score 2):

For what you have described you can simply use the `:index` attribute:

```
brower.text_field(:name => "asdf", :index => 0).click # get the first element
brower.text_field(:name => "asdf", :index => 1).click # get the second element
```

Or loop over all text_fields with attribute `:name => "asdf"`:

```
browser.text_fields(:name => "asdf").each { |elem| elem.click }
```